# Return SQL Query Run Time in VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a program which runs a number of SQL Query, collecting data and writing to a database, sending emails etc.

What im looking to know is:

Is there a way to record the time it took to run the query?

i.e. Running the Queries in Management Studio returns something like 1.234 seconds. Can i retrieve this information from a .net application.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [StopWatch](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch) object to measure your time

```
    Dim st new Stopwatch()
    st.Start();
    ExecuteTheCodeOfYourQuery()
    st.Stop();
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = st.Elapsed
    Dim elapsedTime as String = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10)
    MessageBox.Show("Exec Time " + elapsedTime)
```

Comment: Steve,This looks the business. Many thanks for getting back so quick.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can use
`SET STATISTICS TIME ON`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx
and the query time will end up in `sys.sysprocesses.cpu` (it wouldn't normally) - if that's any help. That's as far as I've researched :)

Comment: +1 Looks interesting, however, I think that in this way a second read to the database is required.